# Topological properties such that if the subspace has P then the whole space also has P

Tags: general-topology

Is there any topological Property $P$ if it is satisfied on a subspace topology $N$ of a topological space $X$, then it must be satisfied on a topological space $X$. Thanks.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Is there a motivation behind this question?

Answer (score 15):

Not first-countable. Not second-countable. Not Hausdorff. Not regular. Not completely regular. Not T<sub>0</sub>. Not T<sub>1</sub>. Not metrizable.

In general, if $\mathfrak{P}$ is a topological property inherited by subspaces, then the topological property not-$\mathfrak{P}$ is of the kind sought.

Answer (score 10):

Recall that a topological property is called *[hereditary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_property)* if the following holds: If $X$ has the property P and $N$ is subspace of $X$, then $N$ also has the property P.

If you take any hereditary property P, the negation of it $\neg P$ will fulfill the conditions you ask in your post.

In fact, the property $P$ is hereditary if and only if $\neg P$ has fulfills the requirements from your post.

---

In some contexts, results of this type are might be called [reflection theorems](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22reflection+theorems%22+topology). However, as the two formulations are equivalent, they can be formulated as in your post, or dually. Quite often some additional condition is given on the subspace.

The following quote is from *Encyclopedia of General Topology*; Edited by: Klaas Pieter Hart, Jun-iti Nagata and Jerry E. Vaughan, Elsevier, 2003, [p.16](http://books.google.com/books?id=JWyoCRkLFAkC&pg=PA16).

> Generally speaking, a reflection theorem is a theorem of the form "if a set (or a space) $X$ has a property $P$, then there is a subset (or a subspace) $Y$ of a small size (in some sense) satisfying $P$.

Answer (score 3):

Do you consider having a nontrivial open set to be a topological property? $N \not = \emptyset$ implies $X \not = \emptyset$, so $N$ having a nontrivial open set implies that $X$ does too. You could cook up other "properties" like this that satisfy your answer, but in a boring way. (Like that $X$ contains a property $P$ subspace.)

But in general I don't think so - if I can write $X$ as the disjoint union of $N$ and $M$, then most properties I can think of have to be satisfied by $N$ and $M$ in order to be satisfied by $X$ (the separation axioms, for instance). For others (such as connectedness), this is not enough.

But the upshot is that if you hand me a property that a space $N$ has and a space $M$ doesn't, then I think $N \dot \cup M$ is unlikely to have that property. This is especially so if that property can be characterized locally, or by some global characteristic - like that a space being compact implies that every closed set is compact.

I would like to be proved wrong though.